# NullPointer Exception in Lat/Long

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, latitude-longitude

I'm getting a nullpointer exception when I'm trying to grab the latitude and longitude from my GPSTracker class. I'm trying to get the lat and long and add them to the end of my url. Can anyone help me out?

Here's my error.

```
    07-06 13:31:40.451: W/System.err(25222): java.net.MalformedURLException
07-06 13:31:40.451: W/System.err(25222):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:152)
07-06 13:31:40.451: W/System.err(25222):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
07-06 13:31:40.451: W/System.err(25222):    at rafa.weatherapp.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:28)
07-06 13:31:40.451: W/System.err(25222):    at rafa.weatherapp.MainActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:70)
07-06 13:31:40.451: W/System.err(25222):    at rafa.weatherapp.MainActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-06 13:31:40.451: W/System.err(25222):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-06 13:31:40.451: W/System.err(25222):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-06 13:31:40.451: W/System.err(25222):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-06 13:31:40.456: D/GPS Enabled(25222): GPS Enabled
07-06 13:31:40.456: W/System.err(25222):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-06 13:31:40.456: W/System.err(25222):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-06 13:31:40.461: W/System.err(25222):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-06 13:31:40.461: D/AndroidRuntime(25222): Shutting down VM
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/Buffer Error(25222): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
07-06 13:31:40.461: W/dalvikvm(25222): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41749c08)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/JSON Parser(25222): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222): Process: rafa.weatherapp, PID: 25222
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rafa.weatherapp/rafa.weatherapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at rafa.weatherapp.GPSTracker.getLatitude(GPSTracker.java:91)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at rafa.weatherapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
07-06 13:31:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(25222):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my GPSTracker class

```
    public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener{

private final Context mContext;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;   
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;   
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;
Double latitude;
Double longitude;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; //10 meters 
private static final long  MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; //1 minute  
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker (Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled){
            //no network provider is enabled
        } else{
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if(locationManager != null){
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if(location != null){
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled){
                if(location == null){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if(locationManager != null){
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if(location != null){
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location;
}
/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        System.out.print(latitude);
    }

    return latitude;
}
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to show setting alert dialog
 */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    //Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
    //Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings and enable GPS?"); 
    //Setting Icon to Dialog
    //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);
    //On Pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    //on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    //Showing alert message
    alertDialog.show();
}

public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){       
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){        
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){     
}
@Override 
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){        
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){
    return null;
}   
}
```

And here is my MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView weather = null;
    TextView summary = null;
    TextView icon = null;
    JSONObject currentTemperature = null;
    String temperature = "";
    String weatherSummary = "";
    String weatherIcon = "";
    GPSTracker gps;
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;
    String myUrl;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        weather = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather);
        summary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather_summary);
        icon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.string_icon);           
        // we will using AsyncTask during parsing 
        new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();

        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
         myUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/5530508d3568e57848d53bf10cfade1f/" +
                gps.getLatitude() + "," + gps.getLongitude();
    }

   /* public String convertLatitude(){
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        String latitude2 = Double.toString(latitude);

        return latitude2;
    }*/

   /* public String convertLongitude(){
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        String longitude2 = Double.toString(longitude);

        return longitude2;
    }*/

    //do in background method to call JSON Parser
    public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";       

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0){

           try {


                // instantiate our json parser
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                // get json string from url
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(myUrl);


                JSONObject current = json.getJSONObject("currently");
                temperature = current.getString("temperature");

                weatherSummary = current.getString("summary");
                weatherIcon = current.getString("icon");





            } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return myUrl;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {

             weather.setText(temperature);
             summary.setText(weatherSummary);
             icon.setText(weatherIcon);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set myUrl after execution of AsyncTask. It could be null, and that's why you get NullPointerException in logcat:

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(myUrl);

at rafa.weatherapp.MainActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
E/Buffer Error(25222): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at rafa.weatherapp.GPSTracker.getLatitude(GPSTracker.java:91)
```

For this NPE in `getLatitude()`: You're unboxing a `null` `Double` to a primitive `double`. Return a value from the `if (location != null)` branch, e.g.

```
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        System.out.print(latitude);
        return 0.0; // or some other "special" value
    }

    return latitude;
}
```

Comment: ah. this didn't fix it